# How can I run a node script from the command line without installing it and use packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line, node-modules

How can I run a node script from the command line **during development** while giving it access to installed packages `npm install <...>`.? I do not want to install anything.

If I try `node ./bin/my_script.js`, the script does not have access to the packages I've installed.

I've added a line to the root `package.json`:

```
"bin": { "my_script": "./bin/my_script.json"},
```

but can't figure out how to use that line to invoke it **during development, without installation.**

(My goal is to run the script as a Node module, but I'm interested in having it run both as a module and not.)

My ultimate goal is simply to be able to run a node script from the command line, without install, while still accessing packages.

Answer (score 0):

Json files aren't code.

If you have a file in your current directory called helloWorld.js with contents of

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

then `node helloWorld.js` should print "Hello World".

Comment: Typo fixed, thank you.  But my question remains: How can I use a `require` or `import` in `helloWorld.js`? Running `node helloWorld.js` can't find the package.

Comment: If the package is typescript, you'll need a workaround. Otherwise I think you can use `require`

Comment: No, `require` can't find the package - at least not when I try it from a plain vanilla `node myscript.js` execution.